# GNOME Online Accounts - Timeout was reached

Tags: 17.04, dbus, online-accounts

I recently noticed that all of my GNOME online account credentials showed as expired, so I attempted to re-enter them, only to be redirected to a blank page with the text "Timeout was reached". I then decided to remove all of the accounts and their credentials in Seahorse and attempted to try to enter my account credentials again, only to be met with the same "Timeout was reached" message. I have attempted to restart the goa-daemon proccess with the command

> /usr/lib/gnome-online-accounts/goa-daemon --replace

to no avail. Logging in and out and restarting does not help either. Using Ubuntu 17.04 with GNOME 3.24